Rust get length of a string
I am new on Rust and I try to learn the basic syntax to start enjoying this language.
In my code, I ask an input from user and print the length of the entry, but when I enter "test" it return 6 as the length, not 4.
let mut input = String::new();
io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Input error"); // here I enter "test"
println!("{}",input.chars().count()); // return 6

I also tried
println!("{}",input.len());

but it show me the same wrong output. I know the .len() function only show the byte length of the string, but I was thinking that .chars().count() would work, but no.
Can you please help me to find the correct way to get the length of my string?

In short: You are probably on Windows, and there are additional \r\n.

If you want a platform-agnostic comparison, you should probably trim the input's trailing whitespace.
